# stop execution script within condition

Tags: r, break

I have the following code in the script `test.R`:

```
if (x==2){
  stop("the script ends")
}
```

Now I source this script

```
source(test.R)
t <- 2
```

I would like the code to stop if `x==2` and does not go further. However, it continues and assigns `t <- 2`. I can use the function `warnings(options)` but I want to avoid this option and implement a condition within the `if`. Any suggestion?

Comment: How about `stopifnot(x != 2)`

Comment: You call this a script ... are you calling it as something like `Rscript myfile.R`?

Comment: @r2evans yes I am calling this script through another script. however even tough I have an error message the execution continues and I would like to avoid this

Comment: There may be something else going on: I tried a sample script and set `x<-2` then `stop(...)`, and it did not assign `at=1`. Perhaps you should check the `class` and actual value of `x` in your troubleshooting to make sure that your `stop` condition is actually being met.

Comment: Furthermore, *"calling this script through another script"*: are you using `source(...)`, `system("Rscript",...)`, or something else? This is for both the outer script and the inner script.

Comment: @r2evans. thank you. I updated the question to make it more clear for you

Comment: I still think there's something else going on. I tried two scripts where the first is run with `Rscript` and it then `source`s a second script. When the second script uses `stop()`, Rscript errors and nothing more in either script is executed. So I suggest again that perhaps `x` is not "equal" to what you think it is. If it looks like it is "2", then perhaps this is related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Answer (score 1):

The code you list should work as expected.

As an example, I made two scripts, `test.R` and `test2.R`:

1. File `test.R`:

```
if (identical(x, 2)) {
  stop("the script ends")
}
```

(Note: I'm using `identical(x, 2)` as the safer way to check whether `x` equals 2, but `x == 2` would work the same in this example.)

2. File `test2.R`:

```
x <- 1
source("test.R")
t <- 1
print("This should be printed.")

x <- 2
source("test.R")
t <- 2
print("This should not be printed!")
```

Now I run `test2.R` from the console:

```
> t <- 5
> source('test2.R')
[1] "This should be printed."
 Error in eval(ei, envir) : the script ends 
> t
[1] 1
```

We see that the check passed the first time, when `x == 1`, and it failed the second time, when `x == 2`. Therefore, the value of `t` at the end is 1, because the first assignment was run and the second was not.

Comment: I agree with you however if you have a statement after `print("This should not be printed")` such as `t=2` then even you have stop breaker within test then 2 is assigned to t. any idea how to avoid that

Comment: No, that doesn't happen. See expanded answer.

Comment: if you run a script Master.R with source(test2.R) and right after you assign t=2, then I get an error message regarding the source but t=2 is still assign. I would like to break everything after the error (stop all execution)

Answer (score 0):

A while loop can create a condition that you can escape from as you are suggesting:

```
while (TRUE){
    if (x==2) {
        break
    }
}
```

This is assuming that your code is 'all the way to the left' when executing. Seeing a little more might help, or better understanding how x is being set or being used. Note that using something like while(TRUE) might not be best practice, and can lead to infinite execution if you do not exit properly.

Comment: yes this is correct. however if you put a statement after the while loop and you execute this script from another script then the statement is executed

Comment: Have you considered inverting the question here? `if (x!=2) { <continue code> }`

Comment: I think Claus might be more help on this one. If you can pass something from your source file, you could then use an if/else syntax, but I am not aware of the ability to pass variables or conditions through source files in R